# How do i print data from a database in column format?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have created a `models.py` file and created a format for my table. How can I print this out on a web page below. After this I would like to compare it to other data in the database. The data inputted is done via radio buttons ranging via 1-4 (an example of the database layout is attached). I believe is uses something similar to Objects.get? I could be wrong [image]

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    question1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question1_CHOICES)
    question2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question2_CHOICES)
    question3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question3_CHOICES)
    question4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question4_CHOICES)
    question5 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question5_CHOICES)
    question6 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question6_CHOICES)
    question7 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question7_CHOICES)
    question8 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question8_CHOICES)
    question9 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question9_CHOICES)
    question10 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question10_CHOICES)`
```

I have also added the views.py which stores the data just in case.

**Views.py**

```
def question1(request):
    question_form1 = QuestionForm1
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # saves to database
            return render(request, 'music/compare.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'music/failed.html')
    return render(request, 'music/question1.html', locals())
```

Comment: What do you mean *After this I would like to compare it to other data in the database* ?

Comment: I would like to view for example other users who have selected choices 1-4 on the same question. if that make sense so that the user can see how they stack up against each other

Comment: So, you want something different than @user2896976's answer?

Comment: No, This is still a valid question as i was unsure how to display the data from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query all of the rows in a table:

`ModelName.objects.all()`

Then you can pass that to your view:

```
return render(request, 'music/compare.html', {
  "rows": Question.objects.all()
})
```

And use the rows in your template:

```
<table>
  <th>
    <!-- Do your headers here -->
  </th>
{% for row in rows %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.question1}}</td>
    <td>{{row.question2}}</td>
    ...
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```